# ping or curl invalid domains redirects to local server on Linux

Tags: linux, curl, dns, ping

When I try to ping or retrieve an invalid domain, I get redirect to default domain on my local server.
ex: 
trying to ping www.invaliddomainnameexample.com from my server s1.mylocaldomain.com

```
~: ping www.invaliddomainnameexample.com
PING www.invaliddomainnameexample.com.mylocaldomain.com (67.877.87.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mylocaldomain.com (67.877.87.128): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from mylocaldomain.com (67.877.87.128): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
```

or using curl

```
~: curl -I www.invaliddomainnameexample.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 26 Nov 2012 16:09:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 223
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=10
Location: http://mylocaldomain.com/
```

my resolve.conf

```
~: cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Ehm that looks more like a statement than a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only way to fix this is to disallow unknown hosts to be processed by Http server. Though I did that only for local IPs

I use Nginx so the config would be

```
#list of server and local IPs
geo $local {
    default 0;
    34.56.23.0/21 1;
    127.0.0.1/32 1;
}
#Deny access to any host other  
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name  _;

   if ( $local = 1 ){
       return 405;
   }

   rewrite ^(.*) http://mylocaldomain.com$1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that your /etc/resolv.conf also contains a
`search mylocaldomain.com`
statement and there's an „*“ DNS A RR for your domain?

Because then the searchlist is applied, the * record matches, and voilà!

Try `ping www.invaliddomainnameexample.com.` with a dot appended to mark the domain name as a FQDN which prevents applying the searchlist.

Comment: Thanks @fany I added a dot and the result was `ping: unknown host www.invaliddomainnameexample.com.`
But my  /etc/resolv.conf does not have `search mylocaldomain.com` I had this on different CentOS servers. Any idea what else could be the reason?

Comment: What does your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` contain about host name resolution, that is, how does the `hosts:` entry look like?

Comment: here is /etc/nsswitch.conf `hosts: files dns`